# How to correctly reroute arbitrary paths to files for Plug.Static files?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I was thinking of skipping Phoenix since I am just planning to build a demo for a React app that uses some API routes for its state. Seems like an opportunity to familiarize with the underlying tech.

I came up with the following, but it feels very "hardcoded" and I am curious if there is a more elegant solution to achieve the same thing.

```
defmodule DemoApp.Plug.ServeStatic do
  use Plug.Builder

  @static_opts [at: "/", from: "priv/static"]

  plug :default_index
  plug Plug.Static, @static_opts
  plug :default_404
  plug Plug.Static, Keyword.put(@static_opts, :only, ["error_404.html"])

  # Rewrite / to "index.html" so Plug.Static finds a match
  def default_index(%{request_path: "/"} = conn, _opts) do
    %{conn | :path_info => ["index.html"]}
  end
  def default_index(conn, _), do: conn

  # Rewrite everything that wasn't found to an existing error file
  def default_404(conn, _opts) do
    %{conn | :path_info => ["error_404.html"]}
  end
end
```

The idea is to have `/` serve `index.html` without redirect, and serve the contents of an error file whenever something isn't found, instead of a minimal response "404 file not found" string.

Is there a way to achieve this without plugging Plug.Static twice, or is this the way to go? I can also see the catchall `:default_404` collide with my API routes later on, and I am not sure how I would resolve that.

Any input would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use [`Plug.Router`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Router.html) and [`Plug.Conn.send_file/5`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#send_file/5) for this. Here's some code that does what you do but much cleaner:

```
defmodule M do
  use Plug.Router

  plug Plug.Static, at: "/", from: "priv/static"
  plug :match
  plug :dispatch

  get "/" do
    send_file(conn, 200, "priv/static/index.html")
  end

  match _ do
    send_file(conn, 404, "priv/static/404.html")
  end
end
```

As the `:match` and `:dispatch` are plugged in after `Plug.Static`, any files in `priv/static` will be served before falling back to the router, just like Phoenix does.

With these files in `priv/static`:

```
➜ cat priv/static/404.html
404.html
➜ cat priv/static/index.html
index.html
➜ cat priv/static/other.html
other.html
```

Here's how this code works:

```
➜ curl http://localhost:4000
index.html
➜ curl http://localhost:4000/
index.html
➜ curl http://localhost:4000/index.html
index.html
➜ curl http://localhost:4000/other.html
other.html
➜ curl http://localhost:4000/foo
404.html
➜ curl http://localhost:4000/foo/bar
404.html
➜ curl http://localhost:4000/404.html
404.html
➜ curl -s -I http://localhost:4000/foo | grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
➜ curl -s -I http://localhost:4000/foo/bar | grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
➜ curl -s -I http://localhost:4000/404.html | grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for! I checked the `Plug.Router` docs and I was using the built pipeline in the OP in one, but completely forgot that I had all of the `Plug.Conn` methods at my disposal as well. Much appreciated.

Comment: One issue with this approach is that `send_file` doesn't have all of the features of `Plug.Static`, such as setting caching headers like `ETag`. Is there a way to just rewrite the conn's path and forward the modified request to `Plug.Static`?

Comment: You can also combine Plug.Router and Plug.Static to enable file caching: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51155884/285691